# Is it possible to run nvme smart checks when the ssd in adapter enclosure?

Tags: ssd, disk, nvme, smart

I just bought the disk with discount and I also bought enclosure to use old disk as an external storage. But first I wanted to check what is `usage percentage` on the new disc. Unfortunately `nvme` sees only enclosure but not actual ssd. Is there any way to do it without setting it in the laptop?

1. Ubuntu 21.10
2. SSD Samsung 980 PRO
3. Enclosure ASMT ASM236X NVME (0)

It recognizes as `/dev/sda` . I assume it has to be recognized as `/dev/nvme*`

Discs also shows `ASMT ASM236X NVME (0)` instead of `SSD Samsung 980 PRO`

I tried these commands.

> sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.13.0-51-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

> sudo nvme smart-log /dev/sda

```
smart log: Invalid arguement
```

Comment: The smart report should work over USB ( but TRIM probably wont).  Lots of similar issues on Google caused by various things: SATA set to RAID in BIOS/UEFI Setings, Mac disk, firmware updates on disk and motherboard,...maybe you should just try to repartition the disk and forget what's on it.

Comment: Unless directly plugged into system, it is not seen as a NVMe drive. It will be seen as whatever the adapter is or as sda. It is how it is connected, not what it is. You are in effect converting a very fast drive to a standard drive.  I use an SSD in an adapter and it does work very well. But speed limited to how it is connected.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me either, though it detected drive and realtek usb adapter:
`NVMe Self-test cmd with type=0x2, nsid=0xffffffff failed: NVMe admin command 0x14 not supported`
I put the drive into another laptop and booted from a USB key and smartctl worked immediately.